# Header on Napili Spring 17

Tags: community, napili

I have built a community via Napili Winter 16 and I un-checked the tick box to hide header. But I now want to display it. With the Spring 17 the setting have been changed and can't enable the header now

How can I make the standard Napili template header to be visible?

Comment: did any of the below comments address your question? please consider accepting an answer so it may help other.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to check `Hide the header region and navigation`, if you can't do this open a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme to use customer service .

[image]

In your community builder you will see a settings and under the settings make sure your Home and Inner are all using Customer Service Template .

Also as you can see there is a Navigation Menu link where you can add your own menus .Hope that helps

Comment: Each type in Theme Layout is already were setup to "Customer Service'. But Nav bar and header still not visible??

Comment: Raise a support case for this .